# What is the javax.ws.rs MediaType we need to use for JWT response

Tags: jersey, jwt, jax-rs, media-type, http-accept-header

What is the MediaType we can use in @Produces annotation if we are expecting the server to return a JWT response?

for application json we can use,

```
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

But what if we want it to be application/jwt ?

If we use it as below server will return an error saying 
 "No message body writer has been found for response class ...."

```
 @Produces({"application/jwt"})
```

Comment: What is the type returned by the message?

Comment: @LutzHorn Server is sending a JWT. It's actually a JSON response signed and converted into a jwt.

Comment: A JWT is a string like `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`. Is such a string the response your method returns?

Comment: @LutzHorn yes!. Exactly something like that. I hope that is fine? because this is not anything related to authentication or sort of. It's a simple converted response.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```java
@GET
@Produces("application/jwt")
public Response authenticate(...) {
    String jwt = ...;

    return Response.ok(jwt).build();
}
```

This should work.